# Blazor app gives error The specified deps.json [path] does not exist when adding migrations in EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, blazor

Hello so the error is as listed in the title. Whenever I try to connect to my database or create one through EntityFrameworkCore in Blazor app I get an error "The specified deps.json [path] does not exist".

I have been searching for a fix for a very long time now and nothing seems to help. I would really appreciate any advice or tips.

my LaunchSettings.json (if it helps):

[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L21QN.png

If you need any other part of my code please do let me know as I really want to fix this issue.
Thank you for your help and time

Also I have already tried all of the possible suggested fixes I found online. (Restarting my pc, restarting VS,..)

I work in VS 2019 community edition.